# Using Coral dev board as accelerator

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, ubuntu-18.04, google-coral

is there a way to use the dev board as accelerator. I'm trying to run a tpu model on my laptop but using the tpu module of the dev board.

I've configured it properly and ran some models on it. But when I try to use it from my laptop it outputs:

```
Error: No tpu devices detected!
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you'll have to move your code to the devboard and execute it there.
Or you can use a USB Accelerator or PCIe module to use the EdgeTPU on your laptop.
Well, there is also an option of creating a server on the dev board and send data there for inference, but then you'll be hitting network bottle necks.

Reference: https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/issues/58